# Close LogonUser Handle if Failed Logon?

Tags: c++, handle

The LogonUser function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx returns a handle that you can use to impersonate the user, when you are done using it you  call CloseHandle to close it. My question is, do you need to close the handle if the logon attempt fails (ie wrong username or password)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  `LogonUser` returns zero if it fails and no handle is created.  Though, if you do call `CloseHandle` on it, `CloseHandle` should just return `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

Comment: thanks, yeah i was getting ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE when getting the last error to check why the user wasnt able to login, and suspected it was because i was closing an invalid handle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The location pointed to by `phToken` is an "out" parameter, so if `LogonUser()` fails you should not count on it storing any reasonable value. You don't need to call CloseHandle() in such case.